# Fastify response is not printer when object is send back from findOne

Tags: javascript-objects, fastify

I am facing a issue.

From Fastify findOne, I am returning an object like this (I checked it's an instanceOf Object in JS).

```
{"_id":"60e05b4dd15ebd54547b10b4","server":"10.10.10.10","port":3000,"user":"admin","role":"admin"}
```

Now when I am passing the object as-is wrapping in another object's record field, it's not getting printed when trying with some API tester (I am trying with Talend API tester in Chrome).

Only if I put is under JSON.stringfy(whole_object), it's getting logged as this:

```
{"record":{"_id":"60e05b4dd15ebd54547b10b4","server":"10.10.10.10","port":3000,"user":"admin","role":"admin"},"tenancyResourceId":"resource-account-0Sbc3gZI"}
```

My response schema:

```
response: {
                200: {
                    $ref: 'metaservices-record#',
                    description: 'Meta Service Record.'
                },
                '4xx': {
                    $ref: 'error-response#',
                    description: 'Error response'
                }
            }
```

The error-response ref looks like:

```
 fastify.addSchema({
        $id: 'metaservices-record',
        title: "MetaServiceRecord",
        type: 'object',
        description: 'Individual Meta Service record.',
        properties: {
            'record': {
                description: '(Opeque) Meta Service record.',
                type: 'object',
                example: '{ key1: value1, key2: value2, ....., key-n: value-n}',
            },
            'tenancyResourceId': {
                description: 'Meta Service tenancy resource specifier. This is inserted by MetaService infra and for MetaService infrastructure usage only.',
                type: 'string',
                example: 'resource-x67ety733iu',
            }
        },
    });
```

My service code snippet that is returning the object (in fastify.route .. GET)

```
handler: async (request, reply) => {
            const result = await dbDriver.find(reply, getDbName(request.params.serviceName), 
                request.params.collectionName, request.parsedQueryUrl, request.params.recordId, false);
            const returnResult = {'record': result, 'tenancyResourceId': `resource-${request.params.accountId}`};
            reply.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(returnResult));  // <----
        }
```

See at the last line, I had to do a JSON.stringify.

If I omit the stringfy, it does not print anything, like below is coming at API output:

```
{
"record":{},  // <- Empty
"tenancyResourceId": "resource-account-0Sbc3gZI"
}
```

Thanks,
Pradip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your `metaservices-record` schema. You must add the [`additionalProperties`](https://github.com/fastify/fast-json-stringify#additionalProperties) parameter to see all the fields that are not mapped in your JSON schema.

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })

fastify.get('/', {
  schema: {
    response: {
      200: {
        $ref: 'metaservices-record#',
        description: 'Meta Service Record.'
      }
    }
  }
}, async (request, reply) => {
  return { record: { _id: '60e05b4dd15ebd54547b10b4', server: '10.10.10.10', port: 3000, user: 'admin', role: 'admin' }, tenancyResourceId: 'resource-account-0Sbc3gZI' }
})

fastify.addSchema({
  $id: 'metaservices-record',
  title: 'MetaServiceRecord',
  type: 'object',
  description: 'Individual Meta Service record.',
  properties: {
    record: {
      description: '(Opeque) Meta Service record.',
      type: 'object',
      additionalProperties: true,
      example: '{ key1: value1, key2: value2, ....., key-n: value-n}'
    },
    tenancyResourceId: {
      description: 'Meta Service tenancy resource specifier. This is inserted by MetaService infra and for MetaService infrastructure usage only.',
      type: 'string',
      example: 'resource-x67ety733iu'
    }
  }
})

fastify.listen(5050)
```

Moreover, I would suggest to return the object you want to send back to the client instead of call `reply.send` in a `async` handler as [documented](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/main/docs/Routes.md#promise-resolution).

Comment: Thanks. Let me clarify. The app is sending the object as inside record and the tenancyResourceId is what I am inserting in the document, before saving it to DB. So the inserted document has both record object and the tenancyResourceId. So it's there in the response JSON schema.
So I am not sure if I am sending back the additionalProperties here. 
Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The general rule is that, the response schema maps exactly what you send back as output. If a field is not in the response schema, Fastify will hide it. the `additionalProperties` property bypass this check and fastify will return the whole object

Comment: See: my problem is that: The object is 'opaque'. Means I do not know (neither want to control) the data the client is storing inside the MongoDB. I just made it object in the properties under record. Whereas the tenancyResourceId is something I need for my book-keeping.
So are you suggesting the whole stuff should I put inside "additionalProperties", instead of "properties" in the schema definition?
Please suggest.
Thanks.

Comment: `additionalProperties:true` is a flag, it is not something you need to map. please take a look at the docs I have linked in the answer

Comment: Tried out with this:
```
        additionalProperties: true,
```

It did not help. Its sure something I am missing, not able to get it.

Comment: I have added a complete example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps.
One question: the _id, autogenerated by Mongo, by default is not getting included. I had to include it in the schema reference.
Is that expected? (Or there is a way to get the auto generated ID always back)?

Comment: It dependes how you run the insert on mongo. By default the generated id is returned as result from the `insertOne` function. so you should add it to the response object

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am doing insertOne only.
   const result = await getCollection(database, collection).insertOne(document);
    return result.ops[0]; 

The object inserted is:                                        
      record: [Object],                                
      tenancyResourceId: 'resource-account-0Sbc3gZI',  
      _id: 60e3261b3fdc8707ec1632b5                    
    }

So, I guess, it's OK to add the "_id" as string in schema definition to be returned.

Isn't it? (Just want to confirm).